# How to use control thread in c# windows application example

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to create a thread to refresh the text value for the `text box` based on a signal input every few milleseconds.

I tried the following code:

```
public void refreshOverview(){

   //my cases for the different signal to change the value of the text here
   //code here
    case 1:
    test.text=something
    case 2:
    test.text=something2

}

test.Invoke(() => refreshOverview());
```

i got this error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to Delegate

Can anyone show me one simple code example on how to use control thread to change the value of the text based on a method every few milliseconds?

Comment: Use bellow code instead of current lambada expression : test.Invoke(new Action(refreshOverview));

Comment: @MojtabaTajik comment is very important.  You cannot refresh a Windows Forms user interface directly from another thread (i.e., a thread other than the foreground UI thread).  Read up on the Control.Invoke method.

Answer (score 0):

just simply change to:

```
test.Invoke(new Action(() => refreshOverview()));
```

and it will work

Comment: Thanks it is able to built successfully using your above but it does not get refresh at all when i supplied different signals,it works fine when i am not using the thread.Is it because the thread is not running?How do i debug whether the thread is running?

Comment: its should work...
without detailed info i don't know why its not work in you project

please check
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls

Comment: @ThomasKoh, you've had an answer to your question about the error message and have a valid answer. Create a new question about why your signaling is not working, and provide all the relevant code in that question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Invoke and delegate to solve this problem.

```
            test.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                test.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss");
            });
```